# Gnuplot: how to display hours past 24?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with voltage readings that covers a period of some 45 hours. First timestamp is `0:05:00` and last is `45:05:59`. I can `set timefmt` correctly to read the data. My problem is on the output.

If I `set format x "%H:%M"`, I get the right ticks, but the hours are modulo 24, so instead of hour `24` of the readings, gnuplot shows `0`. Is there a way to set the format so it displays running hours instead of hours of a day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is a bit hidden. You won't find it with `help timefmt`, but check `help time_specifiers`. Use `%tH`.

> Time Format Explanation
>
> %tH +/- hours relative to time=0 (does not wrap at 24)
>
> %tM +/- minutes relative to time=0
>
> %tS +/- seconds associated with previous tH or tM field

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.